# Create if condition from string

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

i have a graphical interface where a user could enter a datafilter as a string, like:

```
>= 10 <= 100
```

I like to create an if-condition from this string.

The code i currently got splits the string into a list:

```
import re

def filter_data(string_filter)
     # \s actually not necessary, just for optical reason
     s_filter = r'(\s|>=|>|<=|<|=|OR|AND)'

     splitted_filter = re.split(s_filter, string_filter)
     splitted_filter = list(filter(lambda x: not (x.isspace()) and x, splitted_filter))

     print(splitted_filter)
```

with the given filter string above, the output would be:

```
['>=', '10', '<=', '100']
```

I now like to use this to create the if-condition of it.

My current idea would be to create nested if-statements.

Do you see a better solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't this impose the restriction on user input, for example, if I enter < = 100 then it will problem?

Answer (score 2):

Handle the operations with functions instead of control flow syntax constructs.

For example:

```
from operator import ge

binary_operations = {
    ">=": ge,
    ...
}

splitted_filter = ...
x = ...
result = True
while result and splitted_filter:
    op = splitted_filter.pop(0)
    func = binary_operations[op]
    rhs = splitted_filter.pop(0)
    result = func(x, rhs):
if result:
    # do stuff
```

Comment: I like how this does a whitelist check and gets along without dangerous `eval`s.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably create a dict of operator to function.  For example:

```
operators = {
    '>=': lambda a, b: a >= b,
    '<=': lambda a, b: a <= b,
}
```

Then you can start composing those functions together.

First, to iterate by pairs:

```
def pairs(l):
    assert len(l) % 2 == 0
    for i in range(0, len(l), 2):
        yield (l[i], l[i + 1])
```

Now, apply that to your filter list and build a list of functions:

```
filters_to_apply = []
for op, value in pairs(splitted_filter):
    def filter(record):
        return operators[op](record, value)
    filters_to_apply.append(filter)
```

Finally, apply those filters to your data:

```
if all(f(record) for f in filters_to_apply):
    # Keep the current record
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can string conditions together with `and`.

Instead of

```
 if x >= 10:
   if x <= 100:
     [do stuff]
```

You can generate

```
if x >= 10 and x <= 100:
  [do stuff]
```

Comment: This doesn't address how to go from a list of `[">=", 3]` to the corresponding Python code.  The only obvious intermediate step would be to generate Python source code and exec it.  Most solutions to most problems that involve such a step are best avoided.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone I agree that actually generating code is the worst approach here, if he is not actually writing a code generator. I was under the impression that that (generating python code) was the goal, not executing the test.